# Help with a junction object

Tags: validation, picklist, junction-object

I created a rollup summary on opportunity object to count on object 1. If count > 0 then **field1**= abc else xyz.

I tried the following...

- created roll up count on object 1
- created a formula text on the opportunity as...

IF(Opportunity__r.object1__c , abc, xyz)

It doesn't pass the syntax test. How do have the **field1** with required values?

Comment: If the answers @Bachovski provided helped, please mark it as accepted. If it did not help, then please comment on what didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `Opportunity.Field__c` and not `Opportunity__r.Field__c`. If you are on the same object, you don't even have to specify the object type.

Another thing is, if your formula field is of a type string, you'll have to wrap your values in quotes, so in this case your formula should look like this:

`IF(RollUpSummaryField__c > 0, "abc", "xyz")`